# Can not get CSS and Js files when a changer the route with node js "/: id1 /: id2"?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, routes

I'm triying to get a url localhost:3000/:id1/:id2, and get the page without the CSS,Js and the comand line throw the id with de route of the CSS,Js files, I'm using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in the server.js.

```
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 3.839 ms - 82
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 1.851 ms - 83
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/normalize-css/normalize.css 404 1.611 ms - 73
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/ion.rangeSlider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css 404 1.452 ms - 85
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/ion.rangeSlider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css 404 1.871 ms - 94
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css 404 0.557 ms - 114
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/cropper/dist/cropper.min.css 404 0.569 ms - 74
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/build/css/custom.min.css 404 0.469 ms - 62
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 404 0.423 ms - 71
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 0.506 ms - 80
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js 404 0.532 ms - 72
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js 404 2.042 ms - 68
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/js/moment/moment.min.js 404 2.268 ms - 61
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js 404 0.736 ms - 70
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/ion.rangeSlider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js 404 0.574 ms - 87
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js 404 4.457 ms - 112
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/jquery.inputmask/dist/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js 404 1.682 ms - 102
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js 404 1.751 ms - 81
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/cropper/dist/cropper.min.js 404 0.993 ms - 73
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/build/js/custom.min.js 404 2.035 ms - 60
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js 404 1.143 ms - 88
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js 404 1.010 ms - 94
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js 404 1.433 ms - 97
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js 404 7.671 ms - 99
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js 404 8.009 ms - 92
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js 404 8.510 ms - 92
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js 404 8.020 ms - 92
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js 404 7.865 ms - 105
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js 404 2.839 ms - 99
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js 404 3.921 ms - 103
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js 404 4.959 ms - 101
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/datatables.scroller.min.js 404 5.238 ms - 99
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js 404 6.019 ms - 69
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js 404 6.466 ms - 74
GET /58fe5ea36b4f6d462fc2b2fc/vendors/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js 404 2.859 ms - 72
```

the ideal condition wiil be :

```
 GET /vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 3.839 ms - 82
```

Comment: Does `GET localhost:3000/:id1/:id2` go to a HTML page that has links to all those resources? Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: @Churro,Yes it has them, can influence that?

Comment: of course. When the browser loads the HTML file, it also loads the linked resources, which is why you see all those GET requests.